# Rails: cache name defaults to model's _id rather than cache_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I'm passing an instance of a model to the cache function and want Rails to use `cache_key` as the name of the fragment cache:

```
<% cache @ask do %>
 code
<% end %>
```

But instead it uses the `._id` modifier:

```
Exist fragment? views/50c919b646b5001be700002f (0.8ms)
Read fragment views/50c919b646b5001be700002f (0.0ms)
```

(The id looks like this because i'm using mongoDB). I'm using Rails 3.0.5. 
Why is this happening?

**Edit:** i'm using mongoid 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid Version 2.4.0 introduces the `cache_key` function: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/document.rb#L242:L246

If you can't upgrade you should be fine by doing this in your mode:

```
def cache_key
  # insert your cache key logic here
end
```